# HTML5 Server-Sent Event

Tags: javascript, php, html, real-time, server-sent-events

I am trying to build real time app using SSE.
But it doesn't work when I think I write everything in right way.
Please help me with this problem.
I know websockets is better than SSE but I in beginning
Here is my index.html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Using SSE(Server-sent event)</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("getdata.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {  
        console.log(JSON.parse(event.data));
    };
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is getdata.php page

```
   <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sse", 'root', 'secret');
    $obj = $pdo->query("select * from users");
    $arr = $obj->fetchAll();
    echo "data: ".json_encode($arr);
    flush();
   ?>
```

when i used

```
source.onerror = function(er){
   console.log(er);   
}
```

I got this

```
error { target: EventSource, isTrusted: true, currentTarget: EventSource, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, defaultPrevented: false, composed: false, timeStamp: 5152.813223, cancelBubble: false, originalTarget: EventSource }
```

I tried comment code in html console.log(JSON.parse(event.data));
but it doesn't work too.

Please help understanding how SSE works and what is the wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: define "doesn't work" please. What errors do you get? What unexpected behaviour?

Comment: i used `source.onrror = function(er){ console.log(er); }`  I got this `error { target: EventSource, isTrusted: true, currentTarget: EventSource, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, defaultPrevented: false, composed: false, timeStamp: 5152.813223, cancelBubble: false, originalTarget: EventSource }  `

Comment: right. Well include that in your code in the question then please. Code in comments is hard to read and also people may miss the details

Comment: @ADyson thanks for noting me. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

I found out it why it doesn't work.
I added \n\n

```
echo "data: ".json_encode($arr);
```

so it looks like this

```
echo "data: ".json.encode($arr)."\n\n";
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** (just to leave in accordance for future viewers)

[check](https://primeiralinha.com.br/home2/TESTES/sse.html) (then press F12 in your browser and check "Console" - it's working for me in Firefox and Chrome)

See the code exactly as it are on that server:

sse.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Using SSE(Server-sent event)</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("getdata.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {  
        console.log(JSON.parse(event.data));
    };
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

getdata.php (still mysql, not msqli or PDO because of an old server)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

include("../../admin2/config.inc.php");
connect_db();
$query = mysql_query( "select * from ttbb" ) or die( mysql_error() );
$arr = mysql_fetch_object( $query );
echo "data: ".json_encode($arr)."\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

print:
[image]

Comment: I checked console. it is not working and fire error event.

Comment: check my answer, added a recent print

Comment: like what server configuration maybe wrong? It was wrong... and when I use only string(not json) it works too

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, and most importantly, the PHP script should be running forever, not doing one query and then dying. (If that was your intention, then you don't need a streaming solution, and should just use AJAX.)

Second, you need two LFs after each `data::`. And you (probably) also need `ob_flush()` in addition to just `flush()`. With all three changes it looks like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sse", 'root', 'secret');
while(true){  //Deliberate infinite loop
  $obj = $pdo->query("select * from users");
  $arr = $obj->fetchAll();
  echo "data: ".json_encode($arr)."\n\n";
  @ob_flush();@flush();  //Use @ to suppress v.rare but meaningless errors
  sleep(1);  //Poll the database every second.
  }
```

?>

I've set it (the server) to poll the local database every second. You should adjust this based on the balance of server load against target latency.

**IMPORTANT:** This will send *all* user data to *all* clients, every second. You should redesign your SQL query to only fetch users that have changed since your last query. And then re-design the front-end to be given all users on the first call, and then after that just the changes.